# Java applet gives an error in the browser

Tags: java, applet

I have been reading a book named "Teach Yourself Java in 21 days" by Laura Lemay.I guess the book is a bit old and has been written in early days of java.It describes about making applets as below.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;

public class HelloAgainApplet extends java.applet.Applet {

    Font f = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 36);

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setFont(f);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("Hello again!", 5, 50);
    }
}
```

This applet overrides paint(), one of the major methods described in the previous section. Because the applet doesn't actually do much (all it does is print a couple of words to the screen), and there's not really anything to initialize, you don't need a start() or a stop() or an init() method.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Another Applet</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>My second Java applet says:
<APPLET CODE="HelloAgainApplet.class" WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=50>
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have done the same to practice it, but my browser gives an error as below. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: *"Click for details"*... did you?

Comment: @oldrinb yeah i did.It says "ClassNotFoundException"

Comment: I don't know much about java applets but where is your `main` class ? cause that's when you usually get `ClassNotFoundException` at the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Put your html and class file in same folder.

2) Your html file should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Another Applet</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>My second Java applet says:
    <applet code="HelloAgainApplet.class" width=200 height=50>
    </applet>
</body>
</html>
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: Yeah it did fix the problem.But what was the issue?WHy do i need this <meta> and <Doctype> tags

Comment: oh okay.So does it mean that my browser automatically uses htlml5 to read webpages? What happens to all of the webpages which are on web written with just html?

Comment: Something really weird is happening! I will have to ask other members.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can explain me what is happening after you have cleared the doubt.Thanks :)

Comment: Look: I tried to figure out why your html file doesn't work (although file seems correct). I removed: <!DOCTYPE.... and <meta... in my file and it still worked. Only diferrence between my and your html file was in lower and upper cases, so I corrected tags in your file so it has lower cases. That was the point when my and your html were absolutely same. I runned my: It worked, I runned yours: It didn't work. See...Thats a weird thing.

Comment: of course I tried removing the tags as you said in ur code, and it worked.That is really weird.

Comment: I went through the internet and found this  " In the past it did not matter whether you used lower case or upper case when entering HTML tags or HTML tag attributes but with XHTML lower case is required. In preparation for future upgrades, use lower case HTML tags and HTML tag attributes now and save yourself some work later."

Comment: So, correct your html file so it has lower case tags. I did that and it still didn't work.

Comment: Yeah.I did what you said, and you are correct.This thing is really weird